# FPR (False Positive Rate), ложные положительные срабатывания

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, big-data

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посчитать число ложных положительных срабатываний (`FPR`) относительно третьего класса для следующей матрицы ошибок (`confusion matrix`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам необходимо посчитать не FPR, а FP! Или вам нужно посчитать не число, а долю.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более подробный ответ. Почему вы так считаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
       FP      FP             14+5
FPR = ---- = ------- = ----------------- = 0.106
       N     FP + TN    40+50+23+47+14+5
```

[обозначения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix):

```
FPR:  False Positive Rate (FPR)
FP:   False Positive  (FP)
N:    condition negative (N)
TN:   True Negative (TN)
```

Comment: А если с помощью sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix в python.  как можно получить FP,FN,TN,TP?

Comment: @Андрей, по-моему самому надо считать... [вот пример](http://notmatthancock.github.io/2015/10/28/confusion-matrix.html)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что a(x) - предсказанное значение, а y - реальное? И считается доля неправильных предсказаний, если предсказанным значением было a(x)=3?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, вы все правильно поняли)

Answer (score 1):

В хелпе  sklearn есть пример, но вот не могу понять как его верно использовать. На данный момент у меня csv файл с одним признаком и одним классификаторов (два столбца, y_true, y_pred)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот метод будет работать только для `confusion matrix` размерности 2 x 2

Answer (score 0):

**Число** ложных положительных срабатываний для третьего класса = 14 + 5 = 19

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более подробный ответ. Почему вы так считаете?